# ¿Cómo obtener múltiples input file dentro de una tabla?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

amigos. Espero me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema.
Tengo una tabla que contiene varias filas de input file, quiero hacer que cada vez que se cargue un archivo se envíe al servidor, el problema que tengo es que cuando cargo un archivo, este va al servidor correctamente, pero cuando cargo un archivo diferente en otro input file, el archivo que se va al servidor es el primer archivo que cargué. Sin importar qué input file de cualquier fila, siempre toma el primero que subí.

Aun soy principiante usando javascript. 
Ojalá me puedan ayudar.
Gracias

```
<table id="tabla">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>PLANTILLA</th>
  </tr> 
 </thead> 
 <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.plantillas)
        {
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <form>
                   <input type="file" name="evidencia" class="archivo"/>
                 </form>
              </td>
         </tr>
        }
 </tbody> 
</table>
<script>
 $("#tablaX").on("change", ".archive", function () {
        var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(1));

        enviarArchivo(formdata);
    });

    function enviarArchivo(formdata) {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/Dependencia/Excel');
        xhr.send(formdata);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                alert("ok" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        }

    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

tu problema es que siempre obtines el 1 con `get(1)`:

debes hacer referencia a jquery `$(this).files[0]` o a javascript puro `event.target.files[0]`:

```
 $('#tablaX').on("change", 'input[type="file"]', function (event) {
        // $(this).files[0] or event.target.files[0]

        // opcion 1 pasandolo directo con cualquiera de las 2 formas:
        var formdata = new FormData($(this));
        var formdata = new FormData(event.target);

        // opcion 2 pasandolo con append
         var formdata = new FormData();
         formData.append(event.target.name , event.target.files[0]);
         formData.append($(this).attr("name") , $(this).files[0]);

        enviarArchivo(formdata);
    });
```